# Zabbix 6.4 - Use macro {HOST.DESCRIPTION} in title of Host, Trigger, Inventory

Tags: triggers, macros, title, host, zabbix

everyone. I've come across a problem I can't solve. I need to somehow auto-complete the Host Description to the Host name. Another use I would have is also as a Trigger name {TRIGGER.NAME} - {HOST.DESCRIPTION}, but when I type the macro into Title like this, it only shows "{TRIGGER.NAME} - {HOST.DESCRIPTION} without adding the value. According to the documentation this is possible, so what am I doing wrong that it doesn't work ? For complete information I use Zabbix version 6.4
Really thanks for you help

ON} without adding the value. According to the documentation this is possible, so what am I doing wrong that it doesn't work ? For complete information I use Zabbix version 6.4

Answer (score 0):

You can see the supported location of each macro at https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/6.4/en/manual/appendix/macros/supported_by_location

You cannot use `{HOST.DESCRIPTION}` as Host name. Are you trying to customize your notifications? You can send both `{HOST.HOST}` and `{HOST.DESCRIPTION}` in trigger-based notifications and commands.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Now I have created a Trigger and I am intentionally starting and stopping it to test the problem, but when I typed updater - {HOST.HOST} - {HOST.DESCRIPTION} in the Trigger name -> the filled field was only {HOST.HOST} (PC name) but only {HOST.DESCRIPTION} was left in the {HOST.DESCRIPTION} field. Do you have any more tips please ?

Comment: the trigger name is not a notification, an example of notification is an email message sent from a trigger action